# Successfully added line per value in a row. But unable to add 3rd column from row

Tags: excel, vba

Have had success with the below (taken another post), but need to add a 3rd column pulling from a row range. My current addition doesn't populate down the full range A1:G23.
Please help.

```
Sub OneColumnData()
    Dim rng As Range, ids As Range, sets As Range, arr() As Variant, rw As Integer, col As Integer, counter As Integer

    Set rng = Range("A1:G23")
    Set ID = Range("H1:H23")
    Set sets = Range("A24:G24")

    arr = rng.Value
    counter = 1

    rng.ClearContents

    For rw = 1 To UBound(arr, 1)
        For col = 1 To UBound(arr, 2)
            If arr(rw, col) <> vbNullString Then
                Range("O" & counter) = arr(rw, col)
                Range("P" & counter) = ID(rw)
                Range("Q" & counter) = sets(rw, col)
                counter = counter + 1
            End If
        Next col
    Next rw
End Sub
```

Comment: source: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24762774/excel-macro-for-each-cell-with-a-value-in-a-row-insert-a-row-below-with-that-v

Comment: `Range("Q" & counter) = sets(1, col)` since `sets` only has one "row"